# Batch script to copy text lines from one textpad to another, and do some other things

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this notepad file filled with a long list of lines...
Like this:

```
MCDXY22 = 
    (DESCRIPTION = 
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xyzbdk012)(PORT = 11234)
       (CONNECT_DATA = 
          (SERVER = DEDICATED)
          (SERVICE_NAME = MCDXY22)))
```

Notepad is filled with those. Each set is separated by a single emtpy line.
What I have to do is copy all those sets of lines to another notepad file and do a few changes...-->

```
define DYLINK = MCDXY22
define DYLINK_PYS = ???
define DYLINK_XCSR = (DESCRIPTION = 
           (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xyzbdk012)(PORT = 11234)
           (CONNECT_DATA = 
              (SERVER = DEDICATED)
              (SERVICE_NAME = MCDXY22)))
```

Does this make sense?

This is what the final product should look like. I understand what should happen and pseudo code and stuff, but, just can't figure it out. If I do this manually, it will take me hours n hours... :)

Thanks! Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Your question is cryptically for me.

Comment: Does the string MCDXY22 change for each block? How about the Host and Port?

Comment: @Endoro, basically, i have long list of strings like in that 1st block up there. That is just one piece. And they are all separated by a single white/empty line. And, I need to copy them over one by one and basically they should end up like on the 2nd block of strings up there. Something like, copy X bring it over and make 'define DYLINK' = to that X...so on so. But, can't do that actual code :) Hope, it makes sense now... Thanks

Comment: @MattWilliamson, yes, they do change. But, the style of the block doesn't. I was thinking about maybe, saying...from the first line read until the 1st empty space and copy it over and make 'define DYLINK' equal to it...THEN the 2nd line has 'define DYLINK_PYS = ???' hardcoded. THEN, read the rest of the lines until it sees WHITE/EMPTY LINE, and copies it over and makes 'define DYLINK_XCSR' equal to it...etc...

Comment: 1) do you want to change the first three lines only? 2) do you show the entire "block" or are there additional lines beneath? 3) what are the "???" on the second line?

Comment: @Endoro, 1) yes, pretty much. Those first three lines are the main changes you see on the second block. 2) This is just one example block. There are many more of these. Exact same, but with differen port numbers, and DYLINK variables, hosts, etc. 3) those '???' are just there. Nothing important. They will be updated later. For now, that line can be hard-coded into the script.

Comment: Is there a constant part in the first line "MCDXY22"?

Comment: @Endoro, no, not really. Few of the letters might be the same on some blocks, but they change.

Comment: Implementing this in batch would be a pain. Would VBScript or PowerShell be an option?

Comment: It would help to see the actual file - as batch relies heavily on the format of the blocks.  Can you provide a file to download someplace?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, yes, vbscript or powershell would be totally fine

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript something like this should work:

```
filename = WScript.Arguments(0)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^\S"

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  line = f.ReadLine
  If re.Test(line) Then
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "define DYLINK = " & line
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "define DYLINK_PYS = ???"
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "define DYLINK_XCSR = " & LTrim(f.ReadLine)
  Else
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine line
  End If
Loop

f.Close
```

Run the script like this:

```
cscript //NoLogo script.vbs C:\input.txt >C:\output.txt
```

and it will read `C:\input.txt` and print the modified content of the file to `StdOut` where you can redirect it to an output file.

Comment: if I want to add another hard-coded line after WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "define DYLINK_XCSR = " & LTrim(f.ReadLine), how can I do that? I tried using "WScript.StdOut.WriteLine" and then the line that I wanted to add, but it is adding it in the middle of the previous line...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works. Set input and output to the path to `input.txt` and `output.txt` respectively.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set input=path to\input.txt
set output=path to\output.txt

set count=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%g in ("%input%") do call :process "%%g"
goto :eof

:process
set /a count+=1
set line=%1
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%i in (%line%) do set first=%%i&set rest=%%j
set "line=%line:~1%
if "%first:~0,1%" neq "(" set count=1&echo.>>"%output%"
if %count%==1 echo define %first%1>>"%output%"
if %count%==2 echo define DYLINK_PYS = ???>>"%output%"
if %count%==2 echo define DYLINK_XCSR = %first% %rest%1>>"%output%"
if %count% gtr 2 echo %line%1>>"%output%"
```

Notes:

I was not able to find a way to detect a newline, so I checked whether the first character of the line is a `(`. If it isn't, it resets `%count%` and `echo`s a newline. If for some reason there is a bracket before the first line, this code will not work..

The `1>>` is to prevent any numbers at the end of `%line%` to mess up with the appending.

`for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%i in (%line%)` and `set "line=%line:~1%` are not syntax errors, `%line%` already contains quotes so..